# Icon pointing to app upgraded through Play Store no longer works. What's up with that?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, launcher, app-market-link

Sometimes when an app is upgraded through the Play Store, the icon for it in the launcher no longer points to the app.  Other times, it works fine.  What's up with that?  Seems totally random for which apps it happens with and when.  Why does it happen?

***Update***: Andrew asked what happens if it doesn't point to the app.  Great question.  The launcher presents a dialog box that states: *"Item is not installed.  Search Google Play, or pick another app?"*  It has three buttons, which are: *Cancel, Select app, Play Store*.  I also should mention this happens on multiple devices running KitKat.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue a little bit? When it's no longer pointing to the app, what does really happen? (Cannot open? Open to random app? Any error message?)

Comment: @AndrewT. Great questions.  I updated the question to answer yours!

Comment: Mostly the shortcut associated with the app is not valid after upgrading. This is associated with that particular app rather than the phone/OS. The thing can be done is removing the shortcut and adding the shortcut again.

Comment: Ah, that dialog. I remember I have seen it before, maybe from self-experience, or on somewhere else, but now I couldn't remember it. Will try to research it again. Meanwhile, please mention the device model and Android version, just in case it's related.